# Move struct into a separate file without splitting into a separate module?

Tags: module, rust

I have this file hierarchy:

```
main.rs
protocol/
protocol/mod.rs
protocol/struct.rs
```

In `struct.rs`:

```
pub struct Struct {
    members: i8
}

impl Struct {
    pub fn new() -> Struct {
        Struct { 4 }
    }
}
```

How do I access it as:

```
mod protocol;
protocol::Struct::new();
// As opposed to:
// protocol::struct::Struct::new();
```

I've tried various combinations of `pub` `use` and `mod` but admittedly I'm poking at things blindly.

Is it possible to split a struct (and it's `impl`) into a separate file without having to create a new mod?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The short answer: use `pub use Type` in your `mod.rs`. A full example follows:

My structure:

```
src/
├── main.rs
├── protocol
│   └── thing.rs
└── protocol.rs
```

**main.rs**

```
mod protocol;

fn main() {
    let a = protocol::Thing::new();
    println!("Hello, {:?}", a);
}
```

**protocol.rs**

```
pub use self::thing::Thing;
mod thing;
```

**protocol/thing.rs**

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Thing(i8);

impl Thing {
    pub fn new() -> Thing { Thing(4) }
}
```

As a housekeeping bit, don't call files the same thing as language keywords. `struct` causes compilation problems, so I renamed it. Also, your struct creation syntax was incorrect, so I picked the shorter version for this example ^_^.

And to answer the question posed in your title: Without using esoteric features, a file always creates a new module — you *can't* put something into a different file without also putting it in a different module. You can re-export the type so it doesn't look like it though.

Further explanation: The `mod` keyword tells the compiler to look for a file by that name and reference it from the current file as a module. For example, `mod protocol;` will look for a file `protocol.rs` and behave as if it had included its contents, similar to:

```
mod protocol {
    // ... contents here
};
```

See [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/split.html) for more details.

Comment: Haha, I thrashed about getting that to compile myself. I don't know that I've usually gone deeper than a single level of modules. I feel like wider and flatter is more common in the Rust I've seen.

Comment: Nitpick: there's the `include!` macro, which *could* be used to split a single module into multiple files. That's arguably a misuse of it though, since AFAIU it was added to cater code generation scenarios

Comment: @RenatoZannon: `include!` is something that should be avoided at significant cost; it’s got a number of rather weird quirks and is not simple to use properly.

Answer (score 2):

With `mod.rs`:

```
src/
├── main.rs
└── protocol
    ├── mod.rs
    └── thing.rs
```

**protocol/thing.rs**

```
pub struct Struct {
    members: i8
}

impl Struct {
    pub fn new() -> Struct {
        Struct { members: 4 }
    }
}
```

**protocol/mod.rs**

```
pub mod thing;
```

**main.rs**

```
mod protocol;

fn main() {
    protocol::thing::Struct::new();
}
```